# How can I partially GROUP BY columns while picking values based on a condition for others?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, subquery, window-functions

Is there a way for me to group my data by Week while ensuring that for some columns, I get the value where RN= 1? I have hundreds of columns in my data and only some need to be "where RN = 1"; the ones with MTD in the name.

max([MTD Value] as [MTD Value] won't work as RN = 1 is not always the highest value in the Week (cases where the month changes in the middle of the week)

[image: Sample]

My experience with SQL is limited and if the answer lies in a subquery, I may need some assistance if possible.

What I intend to get out of that is this:

[image]

I intend on summing all my data except for the select few "MTD" tags.

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: Apologies, it's been edited now with a visual representation of the intended result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to compute the max `daily_value` per week, and then filter on `rn = 1`:

```
select date, week, max_daily_value as daily_value, mtd_value
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        max(daily_value) over(partition by week) max_daily_value 
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much GMB. A whole college degree and my SQL knowledge still scrapes the surface. Will keep this in mind for the future.